# Not returning response of HttpRequest on partial content C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, httprequest, httpresponse, sendasync

Code that did work now all of a suddent not working due to not returning response of HttpRequest on partial content C# UWPDropbox, Google Drive & Onedrive.

I have a feeling that a Visual Studio or Windows 10 SDK upgrade caused this or maybe .Net has a change I am not aware of....

Has anyone else faced a similar issue?

Comment: Could you please share more details?  How did you use the `HttpRequest`? *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See:[mcve]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awaiter deadlock with Task return,  solved with out parameters